# AG-Grid-React: How to show No rows to show Overlay message after filter applied if no filtered data

Tags: javascript, filter, overlay, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to show Overlay message 'No rows to show' after applied filter if no data available for specific filter input. I'm not sure how to implement the same.

Comment: I think you can find what you're hoping to achieve here: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/overlays/. What you'd probably want to do is to determine when there are no row data (e.g., `rowData.length === 0`) and use that condition as the `showNoRowsOverlay` flag. Looks like you can also customize the no rows overlay with HTML, using `overlayNoRowsTemplate`, to make it look and say what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used **showNoRowsOverlay()** method in setTimeout due to frequest state updates and its working as i expected. Earlier it was not working due to frequent states update.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            if (selectSummary.total === 0 && gridParams && gridParams.api.getDisplayedRowCount() < 1) {
                gridParams.api.showNoRowsOverlay()
            }
        }, 1000)
        return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
    }, [ selectSummary, fetchRatio ])
```